# Chrome 30 anchor link conflict with the invoke of javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, anchor

```
<a href="javascript:window.close()">close_window</a>
<a href="#a">anchor link</a>
...
...
<a name="a">back</a>
```

There is an anchor text link in my demo page, and when I come to the page first time & click on the close_window button, it works well; but if I first click on the anchor link in the page, then when I click the close_window button, the window.close() method doesn't work any more(also in the Chrome console)...

I was using Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m for test, but when I turn to use IE 8 instead, it works as expected...Why does this happen? What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem recently. It seems like it's a [known bug](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GjsCrvPYGlA). The following hack worked in my case:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close()">close_window</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer~It's really a graceful solution.

Comment: :-) if it solved your problem, you should accept it as an answer, so it won't appear as Unanswered anymore